# Reading Google response JSON files

Tags: node.js, json, google-api

First of  all, I'm new to this so sorry if this is 'common sense' to some of you.

So using the request package for Node.js, I wanted to send an HTTP request to the Google places API and the API responded with a JSON file that I'm having a hard time working with.

My request code:

```
request(url_nearby, {json: true}, function(err, resp, body){
   if(err){
     console.log(err);
   }else{
     console.log(body);
   }
});
```

Example response JSON file (from the documentation):

```
{
"html_attributions" : [],
"results" : [
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.870775,
           "lng" : 151.199025
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/travel_agent-71.png",
     "id" : "21a0b251c9b8392186142c798263e289fe45b4aa",
     "name" : "Rhythmboat Cruises",
     "opening_hours" : {
        "open_now" : true
     },
     "photos" : [
        {
           "height" : 270,
           "html_attributions" : [],
           "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAF-LjFR1ZV93eawe1cU_3QNMCNmaGkowY7CnOf-kcNmPhNnPEG9W979jOuJJ1sGr75rhD5hqKzjD8vbMbSsRnq_Ni3ZIGfY6hKWmsOf3qHKJInkm4h55lzvLAXJVc-Rr4kI9O1tmIblblUpg2oqoq8RIQRMQJhFsTr5s9haxQ07EQHxoUO0ICubVFGYfJiMUPor1GnIWb5i8",
           "width" : 519
        }
     ],
     "place_id" : "ChIJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk",
     "scope" : "GOOGLE",
     "alt_ids" : [
        {
           "place_id" : "D9iJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk",
           "scope" : "APP"
        }
     ],
     "reference" : "CoQBdQAAAFSiijw5-cAV68xdf2O18pKIZ0seJh03u9h9wk_lEdG-cP1dWvp_QGS4SNCBMk_fB06YRsfMrNkINtPez22p5lRIlj5ty_HmcNwcl6GZXbD2RdXsVfLYlQwnZQcnu7ihkjZp_2gk1-fWXql3GQ8-1BEGwgCxG-eaSnIJIBPuIpihEhAY1WYdxPvOWsPnb2-nGb6QGhTipN0lgaLpQTnkcMeAIEvCsSa0Ww",
     "types" : [ "travel_agency", "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
     "vicinity" : "Pyrmont Bay Wharf Darling Dr, Sydney"
   }
  ],
 "status" : "OK"
}
```

So my question is how can I print out only the 'name' element of the JSON request?

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `results` array only contains 2 elements, you can get the first element using `results[0]` and then `name` for the attribute.

Together, it would be: `results[0].name`

In order to get `results`, you many need to grab it from the response body:

```
request(url_nearby, {json: true}, function(err, response){
   if(err){
     console.log(err);
   }else{
     console.log(response.body.results[0].name);
   }
});
```